# How to wrap a method having implicits with another method in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a method with implicits:

```scala
def f(x: String)(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor, mat: ActorMaterializer) = ???
```

And I want to create a helper method like:

```scala
def g1(y: String) = f("uri1" + y)
def g2(y: String) = f("uri2" + y)
```

Of course, this cannot compile as `no implicits found for parameter ex: ExecutionContext` for method `g`.

I don't want to repeat the `implicits` declaration in `g`.
So, what's the idiomatic solution for this case?

Comment: The idiomatic solution is to repeat the implicit declaration. If all the methods are part of the same class, you may move the implicit to the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idiomatic solution is to repeat implicit parameters.

If you repeat the same set of implicit parameters many times then idiomatic solution is to introduce your type class (or just single implicit) instead of that set of implicits and use this type class.

Not idiomatic solution is to introduce macro annotation that will generate implicit parameter section for methods.

Sometimes you can transfer implicits to some level above

```
class MyClass(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext) extends ExecutionContextAware {
  def f(x: String) = ???
  def g(y: String) = f("xxx" + y)
}

trait ExecutionContextAware {
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext
}
```

or

```
trait MyTrait extends ExecutionContextAware {
  def f(x: String) = ???
  def g(y: String) = f("xxx" + y)
}
  
object Impl extends ExecutionContextAware {
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
}

trait ExecutionContextAware {
  implicit def ec: ExecutionContext
}
```

---

> Could you please also give an example with typeclass?

Suppose you have multiple type classes

```
trait TC1[A] {
  def foo = ???
}
trait TC2[A] {
  def bar = ???
}
```

and you have to repeat them in methods

```
def f[A](implicit tc1: TC1[A], tc2: TC2[A]) = ???
```

**1.** Then you can introduce your type class

```
trait TC[A] {
  def foo
  def bar
}
```

express it via `TC1`, `TC2`, ...

```
object TC {
  implicit def mkTC[A](implicit tc1: TC1[A], tc2: TC2[A]): TC[A] = new TC[A] {
    def foo = tc1.foo
    def bar = tc2.bar
  }
}
```

and use it

```
def f[A](implicit tc: TC[A]) = ???
```

**2.** Alternative approach is

```
trait TC[A] {
  implicit def tc1: TC1[A]
  implicit def tc2: TC2[A]
}

object TC {
  implicit def mkTC[A](implicit _tc1: TC1[A], _tc2: TC2[A]): TC[A] = new TC[A] {
    implicit def tc1: TC1[A] = _tc1
    implicit def tc2: TC2[A] = _tc2
  }
}

def f[A](implicit tc: TC[A]) = {
  import tc._
  ???
}
```

---

In your example with `ExecutionContextExecutor`, `ActorMaterializer` (for example following the 2nd approach) you can introduce

```
trait MyImplicit {
  implicit def dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor
  implicit def mat: ActorMaterializer
}
```

and replace

```
def f(x: String)(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor, mat: ActorMaterializer) = ???
```

with

```
def f(x: String)(implicit mi: MyImplicit) = {
  import mi._
  ???
}
```

Comment: Could you please also give an example with `typeclass`? I'm still new to it.

Comment: @user6502167 the [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) solution won't work in your case. Since it is intended for combining multiple implicits in one, but you just have one. But is a good pattern to learn

Comment: I updated the question with multiple implicits. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez