# How to avoid duplication of type bound in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-systems, type-bounds

I have a class with a constrained type parameter.

I've tried with `identity` but the return type is not precise.

And in the method `identityTP`, I need to specify again the constraint

How to avoid to duplicate this constraint with methods that work on this type ?

Here is an example :

```
  sealed trait Location
  case object Single extends Location
  case object Multi extends Location

  final case class Log[L <: Location](l: L)

  def identity(log: Log[_]): Log[_] = log
  def identityTP[L<: Location](log: Log[L]): Log[L] = log
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is not a duplication. `L` in

```
final case class Log[L <: Location](l: L)
```

and `L` in

```
def identityTP[L <: Location](log: Log[L]): Log[L] = log
```

are two completely different type parameters. This could be more clear if you used different identifiers

```
final case class Log[L <: Location](l: L)
def identityTP[L1 <: Location](log: Log[L1]): Log[L1] = log
```

An upper bound for one type parameter doesn't duplicate an upper bound for other type parameter.

Also this is not a duplication because actually upper bounds can be different

```
sealed trait SubLocation extends Location
final case class Log[L <: Location](l: L)
def identityTP[L1 <: SubLocation](log: Log[L1]): Log[L1] = log
```

If you don't want to create the second type parameter you can make `identityTP` nested into `Log` (making it `Log`'s method)

```
final case class Log[L <: Location](l: L) {
  def identityTP: Log[L] = this
}
```

Sometimes it can help if you make `L` a type member rather than type parameter

```
trait Log {
  type L <: Location
  val l: L
}
object Log {
//  def apply[_L <: Location](_l: _L): Log { type L = _L} = new Log {
//    override type L = _L
//    override val l: L = _l
//  }

  def apply[_L <: Location](_l: _L): Log = new Log {
    override type L = _L
    override val l: L = _l
  }
}

//  def identityTP(log: Log): Log = log
def identityTP(log: Log): Log { type L = log.L } = log
```

Notice that although we have to repeat upper bound in `apply` but we don't have in `identityTP`.

Normally it's not a big deal to repeat upper bound when necessary

```
class MyClass[A <: A1]
def foo[A <: A1](mc: MyClass[A]) = ???
def bar[A <: A1](mc: MyClass[A]) = ???
```

When this becomes cumbersome

```
class MyClass[A <: A1, B <: B1, C <: C1]
def foo[A <: A1, B <: B1, C <: C1](mc: MyClass[A, B, C]) = ???
def bar[A <: A1, B <: B1, C <: C1](mc: MyClass[A, B, C]) = ???
```

you should redesign your abstractions. For example

```
trait Tuple {
  type A <: A1
  type B <: B1
  type C <: C1
}
class MyClass[T <: Tuple]
def foo[T <: Tuple](mc: MyClass[T]) = {
  //T#A, T#B, T#C instead of A, B, C
  ???
}
```

or

```
class MyClass[T <: Tuple](val t: T)
//class MyClass(val t: Tuple)

def foo[T <: Tuple](mc: MyClass[T]) = {
//def foo(mc: MyClass) = {
  import mc.t
  //t.A, t.B, t.C instead of A, B, C
  ???
}
```

Also sometimes you can play with replacing type bounds with type constraints

```
final case class Log[L](l: L)(implicit ev: L <:< Location)
def identityTP[L](log: Log[L])(implicit ev: L <:< Location): Log[L] = log
```

Although this doesn't remove repetitions but there are ways to fight against repetitions among implicit parameters as well (type classes). See [How to wrap a method having implicits with another method in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175012/how-to-wrap-a-method-having-implicits-with-another-method-in-scala/)