# How to define a type for a generic type

Tags: scala, generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

Say I have the following code:

```
trait Trait[T <: Trait[T]] {
  def merge(t: T): T
}

case class A[T <: Trait[T]](t: T, i: Int)
case class B[T <: Trait[T]](t: T, str: String)
```

Is there a way I can define a type to abbreviate my definitions of classes A and B?

So something like:

```
type T2 = _ <: Trait[T2] // ???
case class A[T2](t: T2, i: Int)
case class B[T2](t: T2, str: String)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't want an alias for a type, you want an alias for a bound.

Please see [How to avoid duplication of type bound in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731473/how-to-avoid-duplication-of-type-bound-in-scala)

Briefly, **you should keep F-bounds wherever you need them.** Actually, this is not a code duplication. Type parameter `T` of `Trait`, `A`, `B` are actually three different type parameters, which can have different bounds.

But theoretically you can abbreviate bounds with a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html), although this is not worth it and generally can be dangerous, because this can be surprising for your team mates, can make debugging more complicated and can confuse your IDE

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class fbound extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro FBoundMacro.impl
}

object FBoundMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    def addFBound(tparam: Tree): Tree = tparam match {
      case q"$mods type $name[..$tparams] >: $low <: $high" =>
        val tparamsNames = tparams.map {
          case q"$_ type $nme[..$_] >: $_ <: $_" => nme
        }
        val fBound = tq"Trait[$name[..$tparamsNames]]"
        val high1 = high match {
          case tq"$EmptyTree" => fBound
          case tq"..$withTypes { ..$refinements }" =>
            val withTypes1 = withTypes :+ fBound
            tq"..$withTypes1 { ..$refinements }"
          case tq"$typ" => tq"$typ with $fBound"
        }
        q"$mods type $name[..$tparams] >: $low <: $high1"
    }

    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val tparams1 = addFBound(tparams.head) :: tparams.tail
        q"""
          $mods class $tpname[..$tparams1] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }
          ..$tail
        """
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
trait Trait[T <: Trait[T]] {
  def merge(t: T): T
}

@fbound case class A[T](t: T, i: Int)
@fbound case class B[T](t: T, str: String)

//scalac: {
//  case class A[T <: Trait[T]] extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val t: T = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val i: Int = _;
//    def <init>(t: T, i: Int) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}
//scalac: {
//  case class B[T <: Trait[T]] extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val t: T = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val str: String = _;
//    def <init>(t: T, str: String) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}
```