# Pass implicit parameter through multiple objects

Tags: scala, implicit

I wonder is it possible to pass implicit params through singletons like that

```scala
case class Greet(g: String)

object Foo {
  def greet(name: String)(implicit greet: Greet = Greet("Hello")) = println(greet.g + " " + name)
}

object Bar {
  def greetBar = Foo.greet("Bar")
}


object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val greet: Greet = Greet("Goodbye")
    
    Foo.greet("Sunshine") // Goodbye Sunshine
    Bar.greetBar // Hello Bar
  }
}
```

`Bar.greetBar` doesn't affected by implicit value in `main`, but I want it to be affected without passing implicit param to `greetBar`, so is there any way to do something like that? Maybe there is a way to set an implicit for object but in outer of it?

Comment: So you want to do something without doing that?

Comment: Kind of that. I whant to do this to set `Greet` implict for all methods in `Bar`

Comment: Use a **class** as Dmytro suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add implicit parameter to the method

```
object Bar {
  def greetBar(implicit greet: Greet /*= Greet("Hello")*/) = Foo.greet("Bar")
}

implicit val greet: Greet = Greet("Goodbye")
Bar.greetBar // Goodbye Bar
```

or make the object a class and add implicit parameter to the class

```
class Bar(implicit greet: Greet /*= Greet("Hello")*/) {
  def greetBar = Foo.greet("Bar")
}

implicit val greet: Greet = Greet("Goodbye")
(new Bar).greetBar // Goodbye Bar
```

I commented out default value `/*= Greet("Hello")*/`. If you want `greetBar` not to compile when there is no implicit in scope then you should keep it commented out. If you want behavior similar to `greet` (i.e. `Greet("Hello")` when there is no implicit in scope) then you should uncomment it.

Please notice that you can avoid repeating default value if you define lower-priority implicit in companion object

```
case class Greet(g: String)
object Greet {
  implicit val lowPriorityGreet: Greet = Greet("Hello")
}

object Foo {
  def greet(name: String)(implicit greet: Greet) = println(greet.g + " " + name)
}

object Bar {
  def greetBar(implicit greet: Greet) = Foo.greet("Bar")
}
// class Bar(implicit greet: Greet) {
//   def greetBar = Foo.greet("Bar")
// }

implicit val greet: Greet = Greet("Goodbye")

Foo.greet("Sunshine") // Goodbye Sunshine
Bar.greetBar // Goodbye Bar
// (new Bar).greetBar // Goodbye Bar
```

See also
[How to wrap a method having implicits with another method in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175012/how-to-wrap-a-method-having-implicits-with-another-method-in-scala)

> I want to do this to set `Greet` implict for all methods in `Bar`

In principle, you can do this with a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) (but you shouldn't)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
class greetAware extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro GreetAwareMacro.impl
}

object GreetAwareMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val greet = TermName(c.freshName("greet"))
    val implicitGreet = q"""implicit val $greet: Greet = Greet("Hello")"""

    def isImplicit(param: Tree): Boolean = param match {
      case q"$mods val $_: $_ = $_" => mods.hasFlag(Flag.IMPLICIT)
    }

    annottees match {
      case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        val body1 = body.map {
          case q"$mods def $tname[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $expr" =>
            val paramss1 =
              if (paramss.nonEmpty && paramss.last.nonEmpty && isImplicit(paramss.last.head))
                paramss.init :+ (paramss.last :+ implicitGreet)
              else paramss :+ List(implicitGreet)
            q"$mods def $tname[..$tparams](...$paramss1): $tpt = $expr"
          case notMethod => notMethod
        }
        q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body1 }"
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@greetAware
object Foo {
  def greet(name: String) = println(implicitly[Greet].g + " " + name)
}

@greetAware
object Bar {
  def greetBar = Foo.greet("Bar")
  def xxx(i: Int) = ???
  def yyy(i: Int)(implicit s: String) = ???
}

implicit val greet: Greet = Greet("Goodbye")

Foo.greet("Sunshine") // Goodbye Sunshine
Bar.greetBar // Goodbye Bar

//scalac: object Foo extends scala.AnyRef {
//  def <init>() = {
//    super.<init>();
//    ()
//  };
//  def greet(name: String)(implicit greet$macro$1: Greet = Greet("Hello")) = println(implicitly[Greet].g.$plus(" ").$plus(name))
//}
//scalac: object Bar extends scala.AnyRef {
//  def <init>() = {
//    super.<init>();
//    ()
//  };
//  def greetBar(implicit greet$macro$2: Greet = Greet("Hello")) = Foo.greet("Bar");
//  def xxx(i: Int)(implicit greet$macro$2: Greet = Greet("Hello")) = $qmark$qmark$qmark;
//  def yyy(i: Int)(implicit s: String, greet$macro$2: Greet = Greet("Hello")) = $qmark$qmark$qmark
//}
```