# Extending an object with a trait which needs implicit member

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm trying to have a code like below:

```
object MetaData extends CacheParams{}
```

So, since `CacheParams` needs `implicit val p:Parameters`, I tried:

`object MetaData (implicit val p: Parameters) extends CacheParams`

But it seems that I can't pass arguments to an object.

( because it gives error:`traits or objects may not have parameters`)

And if I don't pass any arguments it will give compile error that:

```
[error]: object creation impossible, since value p in trait CacheParams of type Parameters is not defined
```

I have no idea how to make this works. There were a few similar questions, but none of their answers solved my problem. Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not override `p` in the body of object?

Comment: Yeah that would solve my problem. But I wanted to keep the object's body clean and decoupled from the configuration in Parameters, like the classes' bodies that accept the p: Parameters.

Comment: ... or use a class instead of object

Comment: An `object` is a singleton it can not receive parameters because then it would allow creating multiple instances. So either use a `class` or fix the implicits in the object definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I guessed the definition of `CacheParams` correctly

```
trait Parameters

trait CacheParams {
  implicit val p: Parameters
}
```

then you should: (1) replace the object

```
object MetaData /*(implicit val p: Parameters)*/ extends CacheParams

//object creation impossible. Missing implementation for:
//  implicit val p: Parameters // inherited from trait CacheParams
```

with a class

```
class MetaData(implicit val p: Parameters) extends CacheParams
```

or (2) implement the implicit inside the object

```
object MetaData extends CacheParams {
  override implicit val p: Parameters = new Parameters {}
}
```

or

```
implicit val params: Parameters = new Parameters {} // suppose an implicit is in current scope

object MetaData extends CacheParams {
  override implicit val p: Parameters = {
    val p = ??? // hiding above p to avoid ambiguous implicits, null or NPE, see (*) below
    implicitly[Parameters]
  }
}
```

(*) [NullPointerException on implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution)

In (1) you're defining/resolving implicit now in current scope. In (2) you postpone resolving implicit till instantiating the class (resolving implicit in the scope of class constructor call site).

See also [Pass implicit parameter through multiply objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64267742/pass-implicit-parameter-through-multiply-objects)

> Yeah that would solve my problem. But I wanted to keep the object's body clean and decoupled from the configuration in Parameters, like the classes' bodies that accept the `p: Parameters`.

If in (1) you want to decouple the object from "the configuration in `Parameters`" you can try to introduce a trait (`ParamsMaterializer`):

```
object MetaData extends CacheParams with ParamsMaterializer

trait ParamsMaterializer {
  implicit val p: Parameters = new Parameters {}
}
```

or

```
implicit val params: Parameters = new Parameters {} // suppose an implicit is in current scope

object MetaData extends CacheParams with ParamsMaterializer

trait ParamsMaterializer {
  implicit val p: Parameters = {
    val p = ???
    implicitly[Parameters]
  }
}
```