# Is there a workaround for this format parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, openapi, implicit, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am generating the Scala code shown below using the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

```
import examples.openverse.model.{InlineObject, OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful}
import examples.openverse.core.JsonSupport._
import sttp.client3._
import sttp.model.Method

object AuthTokensApi {

def apply(baseUrl: String = "https://api.openverse.engineering/v1") = new AuthTokensApi(baseUrl)
}

def registerApiOauth2(format: String, data: InlineObject
): Request[Either[ResponseException[String, Exception], OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful], Any] =
    basicRequest
      .method(Method.POST, uri"$baseUrl/auth_tokens/register/?format=${ format }")
      .contentType("application/json")
      .body(data)
.response(asJson[OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful])
```

Where `InlineObject` and `OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful` are simply case classes and `JsonSupport` is the following:

```
object JsonSupport extends SttpJson4sApi {
  def enumSerializers: Seq[Serializer[_]] = Seq[Serializer[_]]() :+
    new EnumNameSerializer(AudioReportRequestEnums.Reason) :+
    new EnumNameSerializer(ImageReportRequestEnums.Reason)

  private class EnumNameSerializer[E <: Enumeration: ClassTag](enum: E) extends Serializer[E#Value] {
    import JsonDSL._
    val EnumerationClass: Class[E#Value] = classOf[E#Value]

    def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), E#Value] = {
      case (t @ TypeInfo(EnumerationClass, _), json) if isValid(json) =>
        json match {
          case JString(value) => enum.withName(value)
          case value => throw new MappingException(s"Can't convert $value to $EnumerationClass")
        }
    }

    private[this] def isValid(json: JValue) = json match {
      case JString(value) if enum.values.exists(_.toString == value) => true
      case _ => false
    }

    def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
      case i: E#Value => i.toString
      }
    }

  implicit val format: Formats = DefaultFormats ++ enumSerializers ++ DateSerializers.all
  implicit val serialization: org.json4s.Serialization = org.json4s.jackson.Serialization
}
```

To reproduce I simply call the method `registerApiOauth2` with the corresponding parameters.

The problem is that the compiler crashes because of the `format` parameter with the following errors:

```
No implicit view available from examples.openverse.model.InlineObject => sttp.client3.BasicRequestBody.
      .body(data)
```

```
No org.json4s.Formats found. Try to bring an instance of org.json4s.Formats in scope or use the org.json4s.DefaultFormats.
.response(asJson[OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful])
```

The problems are resolved when I change `format` to any other parameter, such as `frmt`. However, this cannot be done because the generated query parameter must be called as such. This is the first time I came across such a problem and was hoping that there is a workaround. My hunch is that the issue stems from the `JsonSupport` object.

Link to Scastie with an MCVE: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oDmYLP8MQOCMqUYEwhJnDg

Comment: Please prepare [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (what should we do step by step to reproduce the behavior you observe i.e. the compile error). Please provide your imports and library dependencies. A parameter name making impact is weird.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question but this is still not MCVE! I still can't reproduce the behavior you describe. What are your library dependencies (with versions)? I tried to add `"com.softwaremill.sttp.client3" %% "json4s" % "3.8.0"`, `"org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "4.0.5"`. Also I added imports `org.json4s._`, `org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._`, `scala.reflect.ClassTag` and commdented out some unresolved places: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/SKP8oIh0TPizhpzsv7ATOg/15 I can't see difference in behavior with `format` vs. `frmt`.

Comment: Maybe you can demonstrate the behavior at Scastie? (See "Build Settings" there too.)

Comment: I just added a Scastie link. The only issue is that the error persists even when I change the `format` variable. I cannot understand why because on my editor the build passes without any issue with the variable set anything but `format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce. I added import `JsonSupport._` into the class `AuthTokensApi`.

With `format` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/mLtRiWE7SQKySehLJykLAQ doesn't compile.

With `frmt` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/mLtRiWE7SQKySehLJykLAQ/2 compiles.

The behavior is understandable. The parameter `format` of method `registerApiOauth2`

```
def registerApiOauth2(format: String, data: InlineObject)...
```

hides by name the implicit `format` defined inside `JsonSupport`

```
implicit val format: Formats = DefaultFormats ++ enumSerializers ++ DateSerializers.all
```

when an implicit is resoled here

```
def registerApiOauth2(format: String, data: InlineObject)... = {
  ...

  .body(data)(json4sBodySerializer(... /* HERE! */ ..., .....))

  ...
}
```

So try to rename either former or latter. If you can't rename any of them then resolve implicits manually and refer the implicit as `JsonSupport.format`, not just `format`

```
basicRequest
  .method(Method.POST, uri"$baseUrl/auth_tokens/register/?format=${format}")
  .contentType("application/json")
  .body(data)(json4sBodySerializer(JsonSupport.format, serialization))
  .response(asJson[OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful](
    implicitly[Manifest[OAuth2RegistrationSuccessful]],
    JsonSupport.format,
    serialization
  ))
```

You can read about hiding implicits by name more:

[NullPointerException on implicit resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917884/nullpointerexception-on-implicit-resolution)

[Extending an object with a trait which needs implicit member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286575/extending-an-object-with-a-trait-which-needs-implicit-member)

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7788

Simpler example with the same behavior: the code

```
implicit val i: Int = 1
def m()(implicit x: Int) = ???
def m1()(i: String) = {
  m()
}
```

doesn't compile while

```
implicit val i1: Int = 1
def m()(implicit x: Int) = ???
def m1()(i: String) = {
  m()
}
```

and

```
implicit val i: Int = 1
def m()(implicit x: Int) = ???
def m1()(i1: String) = {
  m()
}
```

compile.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you think there is a simpler way of solving it just by editing the imports of the AuthTokensApi?

Comment: @griz Hmm, not sure I understand why you think that imports are relevant. Relevant is the collision of names for parameter and implicit val.

Comment: @griz For example for "simpler example" at the end of my answer (`implicit val i...`) how can imports fix that?